# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn get state

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a DataGridView dgView which I populate with several different Forms, e.g. a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. To handle events, I added

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgView_CellClick);
    ...
}
```

The implementation looks like:

```
private void dgView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Name of CheckBoxColumn")   // this is valid and returns true
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handle single click!");
        // How to get the state of the CheckBoxColumn now ??
    }
 }
```

This is where I am stuck. I already tried different approaches but with no success at all:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cbCol = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn; // does not work
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cbCol = (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)sender; // nor this
if (bool.TryParse(Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), out isBool)) // nor this
{ ... }
```

Could anybody point out how to retrieve the State of this CheckBoxColumn please? Besides, do any other events exist do address the CheckBoxColumn directly? (such as "ValueChanged" or something)

**Update:**
The approach

```
DataGridViewCell dgvCell = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
Console.WriteLine(dgvCell.Value);
```

at least returns true / false at the point of time *before* the value gets changed (or not) by clicking the cell. But all in all there should be a solution to address the CheckBoxColumn directly.

**Solution:**
Sometimes an answer is too obvious to see. The problem I was facing was that the event "CellClick" triggered when clicking on the cell as well as clicking on the checkbox. The proper handling therefore is to use a "CellValueChanged" event instead:

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
 {
      ...
      this.CellValueChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgView_CellValueChanged);
      ...
 }
```

To determine the value of the checkbox I use the same way as stated above:

```
 if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Name of Checkbox")
 {
      bool cbVal = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
 }
```

Comment: do you mean how to retriev the value of a cell of this column?

Comment: Jep, the current value AFTER clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper handling is to use a "CellValueChanged" event:

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
 {
      ...
      this.CellValueChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgView_CellValueChanged);
      ...
 }
```

To determine the value of the checkbox:

```
private void dgView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.ColumnIndex != -1 && Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Name of Checkbox")
     {
         Console.WriteLine( Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to manipulate UI components is by use of Data Bindings. [See for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn.aspx):

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Online Order?" IsThreeState="True" Binding="{Binding OnlineOrderFlag}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) links explains DataGrid usage in detail.
But anyways, have you tried doing QuickWatch the sender to see what is the type of it?

Comment: Thanks, im going to check out.. I debugged a lot, but vs at this point isn't much a help.

Answer (score 0):

you could cast the cell to a checkbox and check if it's checked there...

```
CheckBox chkb = (CheckBox)Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("NameOfYourControl");
```

then just do a check against chkb

```
if (chkb.Checked == true)

{
 //do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: `FindControl()` is `System.Web` namespace - how can this be applied to a DataGridViewCell?

Comment: My mistake, in this case it would be much like what was posed by im_a_noob above, so it would be CheckBox chkb = (CheckBox)Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]; for assigning the value.  -- I work a lot more with asp.net stuff as opposed to form applications, but the same ideals apply to both.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast the value of the cell to bool

```
//check if it's the good column
bool result = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
```

edit : I'm probably missing something in your question but if you update/add detail I will have a look

edit 2 : After the comment,

If you want to do it in the cellClick just reverse the value it give you.

```
bool result = !Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
```

Comment: No, the point is by `rows[e.rowindex].cells[e.columnindex]`  you do access the datagridview, not the checkbox..

Comment: yes but why you need to acces the checkbox? you simply want it's value... or am I missing something?

Comment: No you're right, only its value. There's still a difference between the datagridviewcell and the checkbox itself. So if I click on the cell the same event is triggered as clicking on the checkbox.

Comment: @fiscblog yeah I know that... what's the point? the value of a checkboxcell is a bool (after the proper cast) ... the same as a checkbox value

Comment: `bool result = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;` wouldn't even compile - you would have to parse the value to bool before.

Comment: @fiscblog yeah just cast it before `(bool)Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;`